# How can I change Authentication Mode with SQL Server Data Tools in VS10?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-data-tools

I managed my databases in vs10 with SSDT(SQL Server Data Tools). But after creating a login acoount like "CREATE LOGIN netease WITH PASSWORD = '854032390'", and I tried to add a server, problem happened-login failed. I looked for solutions through the Internet and I want to know how can I change Authentication Mode with SQL Server Data Tools in VS10?

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the connect string in the publish profile.

Comment: thanx for ur comment, I found a solution to my problem above, details in my blog, code there http://tmjfzy.blog.163.com/blog/static/66447025201242863310924/